# Gettext no realiza las traducciones en web PHP

Tags: php, web

Mi sistema es Ubuntu 14.04.1, con apache 2 con PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22

Problema: quiero realizar la traducción de mi aplicación web realizada en PHP con Gettext y no consigo que realice la traducción. Por lo que he creado un proyecto nuevo con lo mínimo imprescindible para hacer funcionar las traducciones.

Mi proyecto tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
TESTGETTEXT (nombre del proyecto)
   - Locale
       - en_GB
            LC_MESSAGES
               en_GB.mo
               en_GB.po
       - es_ES
            LC_MESSAGES
               es_ES.mo
               es_ES.po
   - index.php
```

El contenido de mi `index.php` es el siguiente:

```
session_start();
$language = "es_ES";

if (isset($_GET['language']))
{
    $language = $_GET['language'];
}

putenv("LANG=" . $language);
putenv("LC_ALL={$language}");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

$domain = $language;
bindtextdomain($domain, "./Locale/");
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

if (function_exists("gettext"))
{
    echo _("La función gettext existe");
}
else
{
    echo _("La función gettext no existe");
}


echo '<br>' . $language . '<br>';
echo _("Hola mundo");
```

El contenido de mi archivo `en_GB.po` es el siguiente:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: test\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-08-31 10:38+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2017-08-31 10:39+0100\n"
"Last-Translator: Jonathan López <j.lopez@test.es>\n"
"Language-Team: jlu <j.lopez@test.es>\n"
"Language: en_GB\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.5.4\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _;gettext;gettext_noop\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: /home/jonathan/www/testGettext\n"

#: /home/jonathan/www/testGettext/index.php:22
msgid "La función gettext existe"
msgstr "The function gettext exist"

#: /home/jonathan/www/testGettext/index.php:26
msgid "La función gettext no existe"
msgstr "The function gettext doesn't exists"

#: /home/jonathan/www/testGettext/index.php:31
msgid "Hola mundo"
msgstr "Hello word!"

#: /home/jonathan/www/testGettext/index.php:32
msgid "Hola Jose"
msgstr "Hello Jose"

#~ msgid "Vamos a hacer una web multi-idioma."
#~ msgstr "We will make a multilingual website"
```

Para comprobar que funciona uso las siguientes URL para modificar el idioma:

- localhost/index.php?language=es_ES
- localhost/index.php?language=en_GB

El resultado que obtengo:

```
La función gettext existe
en_GB
Hola mundo
```

y

```
La función gettext existe
es_ES
Hola mundo
```

En ningún caso me realiza las traducciones. ¿Qué es lo que me falla? ¿Cómo puedo averiguar el error?

Comment: Qué tiene que traducir en éste caso? No veo nada a traducir

Comment: Las cadenas _("Hola mundo") y todas las que están entre _() deberían traducirse. ¿No es así?

Comment: @Flowen se refiere a que no has mostrado el contenido de los archivos [`.po`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#PO-Files). Por favor [**EDITA**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/98786/edit) tu respuesta para agregar el contenido.

Comment: Prueba a modificar la siguiente línea, igual es problema de ruta: bindtextdomain($domain, "./Locale");

Comment: @Flowen muchas gracias por tus rápidas respuestas. He probado las siguientes opciones con el mismo resultado: `Locale`, `./Locale` y `./Locale/`. He editado la pregunta para incluir mi archivo `en_GB.po` que es al que quiero traducir.

Comment: El contenido de es_ES cuál es? En este caso el ejemplo que indicas debería acceder a ese fichero. En en_GB no veo nada mal.

Comment: @Jonathan, ¿podrías comprobar las configuraciones locales como te he indicado en mi respuesta? A mí tu código me funciona correctamente una vez activada la local `en_GB`, antes de eso no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gettext no funciona con locales que no estén instalados en el equipo.

Usa `locale -a` para buscar las disponibles en tu sistema:

```
$ locale -a | egrep "^.._..$"
en_AG
en_IN
en_NG
en_ZM
es_CU
```

Como puedes ver en el mío sólo tengo esos. El resto de locales son del tipo:

```
$ locale -a | egrep "^es_.."
es_AR.utf8
es_BO.utf8
es_CL.utf8
es_CO.utf8
es_CR.utf8
es_CU
es_CU.utf8
es_DO.utf8
es_EC.utf8
es_ES.utf8
[...]
es_US.utf8
es_UY.utf8
es_VE.utf8
```

Para instalar nuevos paquetes de locales debes instalarlos, por ejemplo en debian/ubuntu:

```
$ apt-cache search language-pack | egrep "^language-pack-(es|en|fr) "
language-pack-en - actualizaciones de traducción para inglés
language-pack-es - actualizaciones de traducción para el idioma español; castellano
language-pack-fr - actualizaciones de traducción para francés
# Para instalar el paquete de idiomas francés
$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-fr
```

Para activar más disponibles (pero deshabilitados por defecto) debes usar:

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_GB en_GB.utf8
Generating locales...
  en_GB.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

Comprobamos que ya está disponible:

```
$ locale -a | egrep "^.._..$"
en_AG
en_GB
en_IN
en_NG
en_ZM
es_CU
```

A partir de este momento puedo ejecutar tu programa sin problemas.

Comment: ¡¡Perfecto!! ya funciona. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¡De nada! :) me alegra haber sido de ayuda.